# Matching punctuation size to small caps

Tags: punctuation, small-caps

Normal apostrophes are too big for small caps and this is making my running headers look weird.

I'm getting around this by shrinking each apostrophe to `\footnotesize` and lowering it by -0.55ex.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

(Notes.  1: Presumably this applies to other punctuation, but apostrophes are my only immediate concern.  2: I'd rather not scale the font, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/small-digits-for-small-caps), as this leads to kerning issues. 3: In a related vein, at very large font size, apostrophes and quotes look too fat, I find, so I tend, as here, to use a smaller font size and adjust the height using a `\raisebox`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

WOULDN'T'VE --- full caps

{\sc wouldn't've} --- dislike

{\sc wouldn\raisebox{-.055ex}{\footnotesize'}t\raisebox{-.055ex}{\footnotesize'}ve} --- like

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Looks like a good solution to me. Perhaps defining a `\newcommand{\Apost}[1][-0.055ex]{\raisebox{#1}{\footnotesize'}}` would be a good idea.  The optional first paramter in case you ever want to tweak it a bit. You could use also use a `\scalebox` to shrink it a bit.

Comment: I didn't know about `\scalebox`es.  Thanks.  I'll indeed define a short command name, if I end up sticking with the above solution.

Comment: How about `\newcommand{\Apost}[1][0.5ex]{\scalebox{0.6}{\raisebox{#1}{'}}}`?

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment: You are comparing lowercase small caps letter with uppercase letters, but you should also take the other variants into account:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
wouldn't've WOULDN'T'VE  

{\scshape wouldn't've WOULDN'T'VE} 

{\scshape wouldn\raisebox{-.055ex}{\footnotesize'}t\raisebox{-.055ex}{\footnotesize'}ve
WOULDN\raisebox{-.055ex}{\footnotesize'}T\raisebox{-.055ex}{\footnotesize'}VE} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Point taken, but my current purpose is very narrow: I want punctuation size to match character height in running headers, which are in small caps (no lowercase or full caps).

Comment: Then is it not easier to change the running headers to smaller-size full caps? There are lots of packages to change headers. Automatically changing quotes to a special command only in headers (but, I presume, not in TOC or any other places) will be difficult and clunky at best.

Comment: @DanielHarbour -- I have to agree with Jean-Christophe Dubacq: redefining your apostrophes for your small caps headers will need careful attention for things like tables of contents (if you have them, I guess).  Lowering the apostrophe (or re-sizing it) will make it look rather absurd if the entries in the table of contents are not also in small caps (and one would hope they are not!).

Comment: I'm producing a series of pamphlets, so no table of contents.  I tend to avoid small uppercase as a substitute for small caps, because the characters come up a bit thin (though I notice plenty of journals do this).  Nonetheless, I might try the suggestion out if the pamphlets end up as a single book at some point.   Thanks for the suggestions and comments.

Comment: @DanielHarbour: I don't think that you did get my point: Even small caps shape you can have upper and lower case letters. What about names like O'Leary or d'Arcy?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer.  Ah, yes, missed what you were getting at.  In this case, the headers are all phrases of English and Kiowa, so the d'Arcian problem doesn't arise.  (Incidentally, I've seen names like these set all in small caps in headers.  It works fine, except, I think, for MacC- and especially McC-names: e.g., MACCARTHY and MCCLINTOK look odd in either full caps or small caps.  So, I share your reservations about this as an all-purpose formatting style for headers, titles, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to make the apostrophe an active character and define it to use \raisebox only when small caps are in effect.  I have small cap chapter headings and running headings but the table of contents is not small caps.  This works for me:

```
\let\horn@scshape\scshape
\def\scshape{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps,Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=2,WordSpace=1.2}\let\horn@apos\horn@@apos}

\def\horn@apos{'}
\def\horn@@apos{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\kern0.06em'}}

% make ' (apostophe) active for the argument to chapter so we can lower it for small caps
\let\horn@chapter\chapter
\def\chapter{
\begingroup
    \catcode`\'=\active\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'\lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\protect\horn@apos}}
    \horn@@chapter
}

\def\horn@@chapter#1{%
\horn@chapter{#1}
\endgroup
}
```