# Is it possible to write a small caps number in only one place in a tex document?

Tags: small-caps

In a tex document I have `\textsc{exp3}` and I would like to make the `3` a small caps number. Is it possible ?

Here is my code, which uses ACM template.

```
\documentclass[acmlarge]{acmart} 

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}% 
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}% 
\renewcommand\footnotetextauthorsaddresses[1]{}% \pagestyle{plain} 
\fancyfoot{} 

\makeatletter 
\def\runningfoot{\def\@runningfoot{}} 
\def\firstfoot{\def\@firstfoot{}} 
\def\@copyrightspace{\relax} 
\makeatother 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables


\begin{document} 

\title{My Title} 

\author{Me} 

\maketitle 

\thispagestyle{empty} 

This is my file. This is an algorithm, called \textsc{exp3}. Numbers like $1,2,3$ are not small caps. 

\end{document}
```

See the figure below (the first set of numbers; from left to right):

[image]

Comment: What exactly is a "small caps number"? Do you happen to have an example image of what you want?

Comment: I added a figure.

Comment: Do you want *all* numbers in the smallcaps font to be oldstyle, or just the particular example you give?

Comment: Yes that's fine too.

Comment: If you just want it in that place it's easy: just use `\oldstylenums{3}`. If you want it whenever small caps are used, I'd be inclined to use `fontspec`, but since I don't have to set a lot (any!) maths, I'm not sure how well that would play with what you are doing.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185229  Oldstyle numbers aren’t small cap numbers, and very few fonts have the latter.